# string & int not working properly in strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime

In this case `$interval` i am giving as integer means it is working fine returning true, suppose `$interval` i am giving as string  means not working properly returning false.

> scenario 1

```
    <?php
$restDate = "2018-11-21 11:58:55";
$difference = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime($restDate);
$interval = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
if($difference <= $interval){
    $data['passwordResetStatus'] = true;
}else{
    $data['passwordResetStatus'] = false;
}

var_dump($data);
?>
```

> Output

```
array(1) { ["passwordResetStatus"]=> bool(true) }
```

> scenario 2

```
    <?php
$restDate = "2018-11-21 11:58:55";
$difference = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime($restDate);
$interval = "60 * 60 * 24 * 7"; // changes from here
if($difference <= $interval){
    $data['passwordResetStatus'] = true;
}else{
    $data['passwordResetStatus'] = false;
}

var_dump($data);
?>
```

> Output

```
array(1) { ["passwordResetStatus"]=> bool(false) }
```

> My expected out

**scenario 2** also it should return as `array(1) { ["passwordResetStatus"]=> bool(true) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the user input "60*60*24*7", can't the user input "1 week"?

If yes a much safer way than eval is to use strtotime to compute the time.

```
echo strtotime("1 week")-time();
// Same as 60*60*24*7
```

Comment: This is much more intuitive for the user, a link to the possible values would be useful.

Comment: Perhaps more [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you cannot put math equations in string, but if for some reason you got them in string format, and you are sure they will be always is format like this, you can parse it..

f.e.:

```
$interval = array_product(explode('*',"60 * 60 * 24 * 7"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not working with the PHP DateTime classes? Here 's a short solution.

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$rest = new \DateTime('2018-11-21 11:58:55');

$interval = $rest->diff($today);

$passwordValid = $interval->format('%a') >= 7 ? false : true;
```

What I 've done here? First we need todays time. After that we need the time, with which we compare todays time. Both times are DateTime instances. Because of that we can calculate the difference between both time pretty easy. The DateTime class got the `diff` method, which calculates the difference between two DateTime objects. It returns a `DateInterval` object, which holds the difference. Now we can compare the calculated difference with your interval of 7 days.

Pretty easy, hm?